# Clickhouse metrics chart by events log table

Tags: clickhouse

I try to make chart, which shows some kind a time-series metrics of objects status counts, but I do not have this metrics table. I have only table with log of object status changes. How can I achieve that, I need some query, intermediate tables, and probably materialized views, because this log table is huge. Is that possible by Clickhouse?
Log table data is:

```
time                | obj_id | status
2024-01-20 01:00:01 | 1      | 1
2024-01-20 01:00:01 | 2      | 2
2024-01-20 01:00:01 | 3      | 3
2024-01-20 01:00:02 | 2      | 1
2024-01-20 01:00:03 | 3      | 2
2024-01-20 01:00:04 | 1      | 2
2024-01-20 01:00:07 | 2      | 3
```

Then I want to make a time-series graph with metrics, shows how many objects, in each moment have which status, I need query results like this:

```
time                | status | count  
2024-01-20 01:00:01 | 1      | 1      
2024-01-20 01:00:01 | 2      | 1      
2024-01-20 01:00:01 | 3      | 1      
2024-01-20 01:00:02 | 1      | 2      
2024-01-20 01:00:02 | 3      | 1      
2024-01-20 01:00:03 | 1      | 2      
2024-01-20 01:00:03 | 2      | 1      
2024-01-20 01:00:04 | 1      | 1      
2024-01-20 01:00:04 | 2      | 2      
2024-01-20 01:00:05 | 1      | 1      
2024-01-20 01:00:05 | 2      | 2      
2024-01-20 01:00:06 | 1      | 1      
2024-01-20 01:00:06 | 2      | 2      
2024-01-20 01:00:07 | 2      | 2      
2024-01-20 01:00:07 | 3      | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you group by on the time and status, and then count obj_id (or count distinct obj_id)? See below:

```
SELECT 
time, 
status,
count(object_id),
uniq(object_id)
FROM log_table
GROUP BY time, status
```